# python subprocess as different user in windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, visualsvn

I have written the post commit hook in python. In my python script i need to call the application by using another user account. Because post commit hook running as empty environment not a user specific.

Is anyway to call application as specific user in subprocess ?

Note that i have used windows amchine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command to run an application as another user if the pywin32 package is not available in your environment (similar to sudo on *nix).